# What would be the User Agent string for iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X?

Tags: javascript, iphone, user-agent, iphone-x

In a device detection, what would be the user agent for the new iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the user agent string for them:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
```

**Source:**

The iOS 11 firmware model number is `15A372`. [Here is a user agent](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/612389-safari-ios-ipad-webkit) from a beta version of iOS 11, which has the AppleWebKit and Safari version number.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, user agent for iPhone 8, iPhone 8 plus and iPhone X are same. To detect device we need to check screen size of the device.

iPhone 8 - (750px x 1334px)

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1`

iPhone 8 Plus - (1242px x 2208px)

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1`

iPhone X - (1125px x 2436px)

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1`