# Emulate iPhone X on Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, iphone-x

I need to emulate an iPhone X on Chrome. I have found the info below:

```
Height: 5.65 inches (143.6 mm)
Width: 2.79 inches (70.9 mm)
```

Can you tell me which values should I give to the form below?

[**iPhone X sepecifications**](https://www.apple.com/lae/iphone-x/specs/)

[image: unknown form elements]

This is what [**Device pixel ratio (DPR)**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports) is

> If you want to emulate a Retina device from a non-Retina machine or vice versa, adjust the Device pixel ratio. The device pixel ratio (DPR) is the ratio between logical pixels and physical pixels. Devices with Retina displays, such as the Nexus 6P, have higher pixel density than standard devices, which can affect the sharpness and size of visual content.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh/related?hl=en

Comment: refer this link..  http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/iphone-6-screen-size-web-design-tips/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the iPhone X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/), you should enter:

- **375** for the **width**
- **812** for the **height**
- **3** for the **device pixel ratio**

Because the scale factor is 3, you should **divide** the **physical resolution** (1125px × 2436px) **by 3** to get the **logical resolution**.

For the **user agent string**, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46262405/3151675).

Comment: Any `formula` to calculate it?

Comment: @Sampath divide pixel resolution i.e `2436x1125` by 3

Comment: How about `H` and `W`? @SurajRao

Comment: H and W are the physical resolutions of the device divided by the DPR.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope I can do this next time for the `iPhone XX` :D

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that Chrome will emulate the screen size without taking the browser chrome/UI into consideration

Read these for more info:

http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/iphone-6-screen-size-web-design-tips/

http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/ipad-screen-size-guide-web-design-tips/

Answer (score 3):

To calculate Device Pixel Resolution, use the PPI value which is 458ppi according to the link provided.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23958504/4826457),

458/150 = **3 DPR**

To calculate height and width,

use the given physical resolution: 2436x1125-pixel resolution.

- 2436/3 = 812 (Height)
- 1125/3 = 375 (Width)

This is the logical pixel resolution.

For more info:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413366/4826457

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope you can give answer for this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117951/emulate-low-resolution-device-on-the-chrome-dev-tool

Answer (score 2):

First image should be in img directory saved as iphonex.png or change the code starting with img.src
Second image is the screenshot of the result.

Javascript function will dynamically add the iphone x notch.
iPhoneX(); on the first line should run after DOM content loaded.

```
iPhoneX();
window.onresize = window.onorientationchange = function() {
    //Your other functions
    setTimeout(iPhoneX,100);
}

function iPhoneX() {
    if (window.innerWidth == 375 && window.innerHeight == 812) {
        if (!document.getElementById('iphone_layout')) {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.id = 'iphone_layout';
            img.style.position = 'fixed';
            img.style.zIndex = 9999;
            img.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            img.src = 'img/iphonex.png'
            document.body.insertBefore(img,document.body.children[0]);
        }
    } else if (document.getElementById('iphone_layout')) {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('iphone_layout'));
    }
}
```

[image: iphone_layout.png]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What about landscape

Comment: You can do it easily with javascript